# py2exe / cx_Oracle - OCI.dll in the resulting dist

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, py2exe, cx-oracle

I am trying to generate an executable for a python script that uses cx_Oracle module. The resulting distribution folder has OCI.dll in it which I would like to avoid as the target machine might have a different version of Oracle client and I would like to use the dll version present on the target machine.

The py2exe documentation has a page specific to this issue. The link is http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExcludingDlls

This however does not work for me. I have tried with the following but OCI.dll always ends up in the dist folder...I am not sure if I am missing something here...Appreciate your comments.

I have tried with following 2 approaches

```
opts = {"py2exe": {"dll_excludes": "OCI.dll","includes": "decimal",}}
setup(options = opts)
```

and

```
setup(options = {"py2exe": { "dll_excludes": ["oci.dll"]}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this format successfully:

```
options={"py2exe" : {"dll_excludes": ["OCI.dll",], "includes" : ["decimal", ]}})
```